# How to know the maximum offset distance in solidworks that doesn't result a defromed shape

Tags: cad, solidworks, autocad, surface-modelling

using the offset tool on surfaces can result a shape different from the one offset from, as in broken lines or edges instead of curves like this:

[image]

is there a way to know the maximum distance i can offset to without resulting such deformation other than trial and error especially if i dont have designe constrains?

Comment: Is the surface one quilt? Selected as one? Because if its not then there is no expectation for this to work at all

Comment: Quilts is a Creo/Pro-E thing, this would work in SolidWorks selecting one at a time. It looks like the surfaces have been badly made.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Yes, indeed i tested it. It seems like the surfaces simply arent connected (even creo would do this if they vere individually selected, but i dont use creo as much as id like, im more forced to use the underlying engines directly). But underneath the hood even in solidworks there is the same concept as quilt its just named differently (and organized). Which is actually quite enfuriating how many names can you have for the same thing especially since there is a name for them in the step standard.

Comment: So I need to knit the surfaces before this command ?

Comment: @sarah yes the computer needs to know they are logically connected. Which is indeed the innovation of BREP models

Comment: alternatively they need to be made from a existing chain that is allready connected. Most likely your original sketch is malformed somehow.

Comment: If they are not knitted, then 100% that's your issue.